# CSS: Will I face problems, if I construct CSS from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, design-patterns, compatibility

If I detect the browser window size on load, and then create the CSS from jQuery after that, will I then have problems with compatibility or memory use?  Are there any reference for using this as general pattern when designing web apps?

Comment: That probably depends on the extent.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `create the CSS from jQuery`?

Comment: Sounds like you might be better served by css media queries... something like http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sure.. I want to define width, height and general layouts when the webpage loads, using jQuery (detect browser window). It's around 3-5 main div containers.

Answer (score 2):

Propably you are looking for a responsive design. The main idea is that you can use `media` and css to detect user's screen and apply the correct styles. A very descriptive tutorial you can find at [alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) and generally in [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=detect%20window%20size%20for%20css&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#pq=responsive%20css&hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=13&gs_id=2z&xhr=t&q=responsive%20design&qe=cmVzcG9uc2l2ZSBkZQ&qesig=M7wL-S1o-304zBSKUdhsGw&pkc=AFgZ2tkPefvx0AYR1gI7xY-J8hAhI1VnE76nTRHxd_qOUsjy-sc2I9MQPgRuJ90hzVwq2axkjiqBrBmp82HdwEOcpMLFRmyw1g&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-a&hs=rCF&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=responsive%20de&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=adf606fc4c97725b&biw=1920&bih=957).